# Apk size increased by 40mb due to map fonts in assets resource folder (using tomtom api for map)

Tags: android, maps, assets, tomtom, tomtom-android-sdk

I'm using tomtom api to display current location on map. Problem is apk size increased by 40Mb.

[image: see this]

I found that apk size is increased due to map fonts.

1.I tried to use downloadable font like this:

"glyphs": "asset://styles/glyphs/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf" line changed to 
 "glyphs": "mapbox://fonts/mapbox/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf" in jason file.
but assets still getting included in apk.

2.also tried the apk bundle to reduce file and it worked but i want to reduce more.